# Position View on top of Drawable inside ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageView like this:

```
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

This stretches each image to maximum width or height, depending on drawable ratio of width and height.

ImageView takes the whole screen but actual Image doesn't. I would like to position a View on top of that ImageView. View should always be in right corner on top of drawable inside ImageView.

If I just put gravity to right for that View it will always be on the right side of ImageView but not on top of that drawable which is inside ImageView.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the sizes anyway you like, including using `wrap_content`, `fill_parent` and `match_parent`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:gravity="center|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display image on top right corner with below code...

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```